# ¿Como ocultar información de una columna?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

quisiera saber si existe la forma de ocultar información de una columna, lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente,
tengo una columna llamada Estatus, y lo que requiero es, que si el estatus de ese registro viene en 1, me muestre información de la columna "Número telefónico" y si viene en 2, no me muestra la información de "Número telefónico" en ese registro, estoy atorado con esto, realmente no se si se pueda hacer

Mi tabla la hago con **DataTable** este es mi script;

```
  function Recarga() {

    var table = $("#dtRecetas").DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        ajax: {
            url: urlObtieneRecetas,

            dataSrc: ''
        },

        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "GET",
        columns: [
        { className: "text-center", data: "Estatus" },
        { data: "Farmacia" },
        { data: "NombreMedico" },
        { data: "FechaConsulta" },
        { data: "HoraCotizar" },
        {
            data: "Elegibilidad",
            className: "llena-form",
            render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var liga = '';
                if (data != "") {
                    liga = '<a href="AsignacionFarmacias/AsignacionFarmacias?elegibilidad=' + data + '" target="_self"><i class="icon-file6">' + data + '</i></a>';

                } else {
                    liga = '';
                }
                return liga;
            }
        },
        { data: "Derechohabiente" },
        { data: "NumeroTelefono" },
        { className: "text-center", data: "TipoTelefono" },
        { className: "text-center", data: "Contador" }
        ],

        responsive: true,
        "scrollY": 387,
        "scrollX": true,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        language: {
            emptyTable: "<i>No hay datos disponibles en la tabla</i>",
            info: "Del _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_",
            infoEmpty: "Mostrando 0 registros de un total de 0",
            infoFiltered: "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            infoPostFix: "(actualizados)",
            lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros",
            loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
            processing: "Procesando...",
            search: "<span style='font-size:15px;'>Buscar:</sapn>",
            searchPlaceholder: "Dato para buscar",
            zeroRecords: "No se han encontrado coincidencias",

            paginate: {
                first: "Primera",
                last: "Última",
                next: "Siguiente",
                previous: "Anterior"
            }
        },
        ordering: false
    });
}
```

Este es mi **controlador**

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CargaTablaRecetas()
        {

            Recetas objPeticion = new Recetas();
            List<Recetas> ListaRecetas = new List<Recetas>();

            ListaRecetas = await ObtenerRecetas();

            return Json(ListaRecetas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: El propio DataTable tiene su método: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html pero siempre puedes usarl el clásico desde css con un display: none; en dónde te interese.

Comment: Pero lo que quiero es una validación, no solo ocultar, si viene en 1 muestra, si viene en 2 oculta

Comment: Entonces tienes 3 opciones, sin pensar demasiado, buscar el valor de la celda con jQuery o javascript y poner display:none; al td correspondiente o eliminar el valor, usar https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33133/how-to-hide-a-column-in-datatable-based-on-value-in-other-column-in-same-row o https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786046/hide-column-in-a-datatable-with-an-if pero en cualquier caso, no creo que puedas esconder una coumna para unas filas y mostrarlas para otras, tal vez si, ahora mismo me pillas descolocado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para controlar lo que pasa en el campo con `DataTables` tienes que usar [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback), en tu código deberías de validarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var table = $("#dtRecetas").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    ajax: {
        url: urlObtieneRecetas,

        dataSrc: ''
    },

    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "GET",
    //Punto 1.
    rowCallback: function(row, data){
        //Punto 2.
        if ( parseInt(data.nombre_campo_estatus) == 1 ) {
            $('td:eq(0)', row).html( data.nombre_campo_telefono );
        }
        //Punto 3.
        else if ( parseInt(data.nombre_campo_estatus) == 2 ) {
            $('td:eq(6)', row).html( '' );
        }
    }    
    columns: [
    { data: "Estatus" },
    { data: "NombreMedico" },
    { data: "FechaConsulta" },
    { data: "HoraCotizar" },
    { data: "Elegibilidad"},
    { data: "Derechohabiente" },
    { data: "NumeroTelefono" },
    { data: "TipoTelefono" },
    { data: "Contador" }
    ],

    responsive: true,
    "scrollY": 387,
    "scrollX": true,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    ordering: false
});
```

Puntos explicados en el código:

1. Nos ayudamos del [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) de `DataTables`
2. Reemplaza `nombre_campo_telefono` por el nombre del campo que recuperas en tu consulta por ajax para que este tenga el valor de `nombre_campo_telefono`, cuando la condición de que el `estatus` sea igual a `1`
3. Reemplaza `nombre_campo_estatus` por el nombre del campo que recuperas en tu consulta por ajax para que este tenga el valor del estatus a validar, cuando este valor entre en la condición de que el `estatus` sea igual al número `2`, vamos a hacer que en la columna `6` que corresponde  a de `NumeroTelefono`.

Nota:

`td:eq(6)` equivale al elemento `td` de tu fila actual y el `(n)` hace referencia a la posición de la columna empezando desde el número `0` para el primer elemento, etc. Entonces `td:eq(6)` equivale a tu columna `NumeroTelefono`. Por lo tanto `td:eq(0)` equivale a la posición de la columna `Estatus`

Comment: Lo hice de esta manero y no funciono

Comment: rowCallback: function(row, data){
                //Punto 2.
                if (parseInt(data.Estatus) == 1) {
                    $('td:eq(0)', row).html(data.NumeroTelefono);
                }
                    //Punto 3.
                else if (parseInt(data.Estatus) == 2) {
                    $('td:eq(6)', row).html( '' );
                }
            },

Comment: ¿Algún error? ¿puedes decirnoslo?

Comment: ¿Qué error te dio, @DavidCopca? Voy a simularte el ejemplo para que te pueda quedar más claro, ¿vale?

Comment: @Fernando Torres, no me dio error pero, solo no hace nada por ocultar amigo

Comment: Mira en la consola del navegador, debería haber un error.

Comment: @track3r no amigo, no hay error

Comment: Si no hay error, puede ser que simplemente 'td:eq(0)' o 'td:eq(6)' sean selectores incorrectos, asegúrate de eso.

Comment: @track3r no amigo, así tal cual puse mi código en la pregunta así es como lo tengo, y si, el estatus tiene posición 0 y el número de teléfono posición 6

Comment: Oh debe ser alguna versión en especifica de jQuery?

Comment: @DavidCopca ¿Podrías actualizar tu pregunta poniendo el array que te retorna tu petición ajax? Creo que es más fácil que lo hagamos así para simularlo y veamos el proceso.

Comment: @FernandoTorres ya puse tal cual mi código, así es como muestro mi tabla, y la lleno a travez de un metodo y obviamente su respectivo modelo

Comment: Listo amigos ya quedo resuelto, solo le quite el parseInt

Comment: if (data.Estatus == 1) {
                    $('td:eq(7)', row).html(data.NumeroTelefono);
                }
                   
                else {
                    
                    $('td:eq(7)', row).html('');
                }

Comment: Muchas gracias.